# C# How to get row length from a 2D array with changing row sizes

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array with rows that change in length. But with .GetLength(1) i only get the length of the first row in the second dimension.

How can i get the size of any specific row in an array?

Comment: _"with changing row sizes"_ - are you sure you don't have a jagged array? A 2d array doesn't have changing row sizes. You can see the difference here: [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with some example code (a [mre])?

Comment: In dont mean changing row sizes like changing in real time, but the first row can have a size of 10 and the second row a size of maby 15 and so on. Is that more understandable?

Comment: @carlos _"Is that more understandable?"_ - no, because I understood the same information this time as last time, so it's equally understandable.  **But** that sounds like a jagged array, not a 2D array. Please edit your post with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing sounds more like a jagged array (array of arrays). That would look like this:

```
int rowLength = My2dArray[rowIndex].Length;
```

If you really have a 2D array, then **all the rows are required to be the same size,** which is set when you first allocate the array. On the other hand, if you do have a jagged array then [`.GetLength(1)` will throw an exception](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qonl58); it does **not** return the length of the first row as claimed.

Of course, this confusion could be avoided if you showed us how the collection is created and populated.

Comment: Never heard of jagged arrays but it works. Thank you